# Function access query/queries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a project in which I need to determine which functions a given account has access to run.

So essentially, if I give this query an ID, can I get a list of functions that ID has access to execute.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PostgreSQL - sorry :D

Comment: Even if you can call the function, that doesn't mean you have the permission to run it successfully.  Just fyi. A function can select from a table you do not have access to, or the like.

Comment: This is true @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL. I guess I should have made that understanding clear.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me as if you are looking for:

```
select *
from information_schema.routine_privileges
where grantee = 'arthur';
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-routine-privileges.html